# How can I combine multiple lambda functions into one handler for different Cognito triggers in AWS using Go?

Tags: go, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Right now, I have a lambda function that will handle a presign up trigger, and another lambda to handle a custom message trigger. I want to combine both lambda functions into one handler function but I don't know how to do it. THis is what I tried so far:

```
package main

import (
    //imports
)



func presignup(event events.CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup) (events.CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup, error) {
    //pre-sign up code goes here
    
}
func customMessage(event events.CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage) (events.CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage, error) {

   //custom message code goes here
}

func handler[T any](event T) (T, error) {
    switch any(event).(type) {
    case events.CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup:
        return presignup(event)
    case events.CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage:
        return customMessage(event)
    default:
        return event, fmt.Errorf("unknown event type: %T", event)
    }
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}
```

Any help would be great!

I tried using generics and having a switch case to handle the different event types but it ended up throwing me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a generic func as a parameter is not supported by the language. I think you have already seem this error message:

> cannot use generic function handler without instantiation

There is a proposal to [provide some way to refer to a generic function without instantiation](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/52654). But even if this proposal is accepted and implemented, the Lambda framework still doesn't know which one to instantialize.

There must be some differences between the JSON values of `events.CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup` and `events.CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage`. So you can unmarshal the JSON value into an struct accordingly and then call the corresponding handler.

Since you haven't shown the definitions of the struct, I will invent my way to distinguish them. See the demo below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type event struct {
    Type string          `json:"type"`
    Data json.RawMessage `json:"data"`
}

type CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup struct{}

type CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage struct{}

func getData[T CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup | CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage](data json.RawMessage) (T, error) {
    var d T
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &d)
    return d, err
}

func handler(e event) (any, error) {
    switch e.Type {
    case "pre-signup":
        data, err := getData[CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup](e.Data)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return presignup(data)
    case "custom-message":
        data, err := getData[CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage](e.Data)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return customMessage(data)
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unknown event type: %s", e.Type)
    }
}

func presignup(data CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup) (CognitoEventUserPoolsPreSignup, error) {
    return data, nil
}

func customMessage(data CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage) (CognitoEventUserPoolsCustomMessage, error) {
    return data, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}
```

If you want to know more about unmarshaling JSON, read @mkopriva's excellent answers on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A965900+%5Bjson%5D